# Variable select statement in access 2016

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to figure out how to do a select statement that changes what it's selecting based on criteria and that scales on it's own (more or less).  In my reference table I have the criteria as well as the fields that I want to return, but no other fields.  Below is a simplified table.

Reference Table

| Criteria | Field1 | Field 2 | Field3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Yes | No | No |
| B | No | Yes | Yes |
| C | Yes | Yes | Yes |

Data Table

| Other stuff | Criteria | Field1 | Field 2 | Field3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yale | A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| same | B |  | 1 | 1 |
| atlantic | B | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| english | D | 1 | 1 |  |

Expected Return

| Other stuff | Criteria | Field1 | Field 2 | Field3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yale | A | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| same | B | NULL | 1 | 1 |
| atlantic | B | NULL | 1 | 1 |

What I want is only the fields that have a yes in the reference table where the Criteria field in both tables match (if criteria is 'A' only return Field1, etc) per record.  I have some additional math functions to run on these results, so i need the values returned.  Any help the community can provide will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
(P.S. I Have MS Access 2016)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables and use IIf() expressions. Assuming Field1, Field2, Field3 in Reference table are yes/no type, consider:

```
SELECT Data.*, 
IIf([Reference].[Field1],[Data].[Field1],Null) AS F1, 
IIf([Reference].[Field2],[Data].[Field2],Null) AS F2, 
IIf([Reference].[Field3],[Data].[Field3],Null) AS F3
FROM Data INNER JOIN Reference ON Data.Criteria = Reference.Criteria;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this answered my question perfectly.